# How to link code from external files to symbols for HTML5 Canvas project in Flash CC?

Tags: javascript, html, actionscript-3, flash, canvas

We have a long history of making Flash-based games in our studio, and we've been exploring the possibility of moving them over to HTML5.  Our artists really like the Flash IDE, and we have a lot of content already created there, so we were hoping to use Flash CC's HTML5 Canvas export feature to perform the port.

However, after much Googling, I'm not seeing how Adobe intends us to manage external code files in the HTML5 Canvas target, and attach that code to particular symbols (a'la how we would do linkage identifiers in an ActionScript 3 project).  Or if we even can.  All the examples I see move the code into the timeline and run it there, but that sounds like an exercise in frustration to me.

I'd like to be able to - somehow - write a .js file that encapsulates, say, the behavior of an enemy sprite, and another that encapsulates the behavior of the player sprite.  And another that manages presenting the different scenes.  And so on, similar to what you'd do in a normal AS3 project of any size.  That would buy us a lot - we'd get cleaner version control, we could naturally use external editors, etc.

In other words, what's the equivalent of an .as file with something like:

```
 package game {
     import flash.display.MovieClip;
     public class FlyingEnemy extends MovieClip {}
 }
```

...as an external file in Flash CC 2015 HTML5 Canvas targets?  I can convert the AS3 to JavaScript, but how would the JavaScript I write in these external files be brought into the project and associated with the symbols?

Is there no way to do that with Flash CC's HTML5 target?  Do they expect you to move everything into the timeline?  Watching the tutorials on Adobe's site, it appears that cut-and-paste into the timeline is the only straightforward way to get similar functionality into multiple symbols, but there *has* to be some (hopefully documented) manner in which we can organize our large projects in .js files external to the IDE...right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no nice way to link JS classes to symbols in the HTML5 Canvas document type. This is a nicety of Flash and AS3 you don't get with HTML Canvas.

This is the workflow I suggest:

- Like with AS3, write as much of your JS in external .js files as possible. You can use whatever JS workflow you want (I like to use [TypeScript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/), which is like ActionScript 2.0 and has classes, modules, and optional static typing). You will have to manage these external .js files manually in the HTML file or with a JS build tool, since Flash doesn't know about them or compile them like it does with SWFs.
- Create symbols in Flash like you've always done. By default, all symbols somewhere on the timeline are exported by their name. To export the symbol with a different name or without placing it on the timeline, use the "linkage" column in the library; you can't use the "linkage" fields in the symbol properties as with AS3 symbols.
- Using CreateJS you can now instantiate display objects using `new lib.MySymbolName()` and add them to the canvas stage with `addChild`.
- If you use TypeScript, you can even extend symbols using this syntax:

---

```
// "lib" object is what Flash generates to store all the graphics data
declare module lib {
    // declare all your symbols as classes
    export class MySymbol extends createjs.MovieClip { } 
}

// now you can extend a symbol class
class MySymbolClass extends lib.MySymbol {
    constructor(){
        super();
    }
    public move():void {
        this.x += 10;
    }
}

// now you can use your symbol class much like in AS3
var mySymbol = new MySymbolClass();
stage.addChild(mySymbol);

createjs.Ticker.on("tick", function(){
    mySymbol.move()
    stage.update();
});
```

- You can even override the library symbol reference in JS so that when they are constructed at timeline keyframes it uses your class: `lib.MySymbol = MySymbolClass`

Granted, Flash doesn't conveniently set all this up for you like it does with AS3, but once you have set things up the coding strategy is very similar.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Perfect.  This is exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you.

Comment: Actually, I just discovered that you don't have to place symbols in the timeline for them to be exported.  You can double-click the "Linkage" field in the Library, type a classname (like "Clip"), and you can instantiate that symbol to the stage with this code: "stage.addChild( new lib.Clip() );".

Comment: Worth noting that this feature (basically setting a "base" class on symbols in the Flash IDE) is on the list of recommendations we want to make for the next version of Flash CC.